# I get this error when running the R gls command of the nlme package, saying there is an error in parse

Tags: r

I was running a generalized linear model of time series data in R using the glm command of the nlme package as follows:

```
Model7<-gls(Total_rides~tMean+tMean2+prcp+prcp2+`Weekend/Holiday`+Sunset
                       +Days+`Tilikum Dummy`)
```

I got this error:

```
Error in parse(text = paste("~", paste(names, collapse = "+"))) : 
  <text>:1:75: unexpected symbol
1: ~ Total_rides+tMean+tMean2+prcp+prcp2+Weekend/Holiday+Sunset+Days+Tilikum Dummy
```

Comment: It would be easier if you used valid variable names as column names. How did you create a data.frame with slashes and spaces in the column names? The easiest fix is to rename them.

Comment: Thank you, the slash in the column name was how it was written in the Excel file I uploaded. When I created the data frame, it let me, but perhaps that can still lead to errors down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character number 75 is the problem:

```
<text>:1:75
```

As it turns out, it is the space in `Tilikum Dummy`. Rename that column.

Comment: Thank you, not just for the answer, but for helping me learn how to interpret the error message.

Comment: Thank you for also pointing out to me that I need to do that.